# Ordering DICT in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I'm loading data into a python dict, pulled from coinmarketcap's api and then I want to be able to sort it by the rank.
I've had a look online and although I've seen some examples or ordering I just can't get it to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Can anyone help?

```
{
  'data': {
    1: {
      u'last_updated': 1527886475,
      u'name': u'Bitcoin',
      u'symbol': u'BTC',
      u'rank': 1,
      u'total_supply': '17068825.0',
      u'quotes': {
        u'USD': {
          u'market_cap': '127372692798.0',
          u'percent_change_7d': '0.0',
          u'price': '7462.3',
          u'percent_change_24h': '-1.29',
          u'volume_24h': '4962840000.0',
          u'percent_change_1h': '0.03'
        }
      },
      u'max_supply': '21000000.0',
      u'circulating_supply': '17068825.0',
      u'website_slug': u'bitcoin',
      u'id': 1
    },
    825: {
      u'last_updated': 1527886449,
      u'name': u'Tether',
      u'symbol': u'USDT',
      u'rank': 13,
      u'total_supply': '2830109970.0',
      u'quotes': {
        u'USD': {
          u'market_cap': '2508920883.0',
          u'percent_change_7d': '-0.03',
          u'price': '1.00071',
          u'percent_change_24h': '0.01',
          u'volume_24h': '2542980000.0',
          u'percent_change_1h': '0.1'
        }
      },
      u'max_supply': None,
      u'circulating_supply': '2507140814.0',
      u'website_slug': u'tether',
      u'id': 825
    },
    1027: {
      u'last_updated': 1527886459,
      u'name': u'Ethereum',
      u'symbol': u'ETH',
      u'rank': 2,
      u'total_supply': '99807496.0',
      u'quotes': {
        u'USD': {
          u'market_cap': '56961236045.0',
          u'percent_change_7d': '-2.88',
          u'price': '570.711',
          u'percent_change_24h': '-1.62',
          u'volume_24h': '1986760000.0',
          u'percent_change_1h': '-0.39'
        }
      },
      u'max_supply': None,
      u'circulating_supply': '99807496.0',
      u'website_slug': u'ethereum',
      u'id': 1027
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into the `enumerate()` or `dict.iteritems()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.OrderedDict`

**Demo:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print( OrderedDict(sorted(data['data'].items(), key=lambda (x, y): y['rank'])) )
print( OrderedDict(sorted(data['data'].items(), key=lambda (x, y): y['rank'], reverse=True)) )  #Descending order
```

**Output:**

```
OrderedDict([(1, {u'total_supply': '17068825.0', u'quotes': {u'USD': {u'market_cap': '127372692798.0', u'percent_change_7d': '0.0', u'price': '7462.3', u'percent_change_1h': '0.03', u'volume_24h': '4962840000.0', u'percent_change_24h': '-1.29'}}, u'max_supply': '21000000.0', u'last_updated': 1527886475, u'name': u'Bitcoin', u'website_slug': u'bitcoin', u'symbol': u'BTC', u'id': 1, u'rank': 1, u'circulating_supply': '17068825.0'}), (1027, {u'total_supply': '99807496.0', u'quotes': {u'USD': {u'market_cap': '56961236045.0', u'percent_change_7d': '-2.88', u'price': '570.711', u'percent_change_1h': '-0.39', u'volume_24h': '1986760000.0', u'percent_change_24h': '-1.62'}}, u'max_supply': None, u'last_updated': 1527886459, u'name': u'Ethereum', u'website_slug': u'ethereum', u'symbol': u'ETH', u'id': 1027, u'rank': 2, u'circulating_supply': '99807496.0'}), (825, {u'total_supply': '2830109970.0', u'quotes': {u'USD': {u'market_cap': '2508920883.0', u'percent_change_7d': '-0.03', u'price': '1.00071', u'percent_change_1h': '0.1', u'volume_24h': '2542980000.0', u'percent_change_24h': '0.01'}}, u'max_supply': None, u'last_updated': 1527886449, u'name': u'Tether', u'website_slug': u'tether', u'symbol': u'USDT', u'id': 825, u'rank': 13, u'circulating_supply': '2507140814.0'})])
OrderedDict([(825, {u'total_supply': '2830109970.0', u'quotes': {u'USD': {u'market_cap': '2508920883.0', u'percent_change_7d': '-0.03', u'price': '1.00071', u'percent_change_1h': '0.1', u'volume_24h': '2542980000.0', u'percent_change_24h': '0.01'}}, u'max_supply': None, u'last_updated': 1527886449, u'name': u'Tether', u'website_slug': u'tether', u'symbol': u'USDT', u'id': 825, u'rank': 13, u'circulating_supply': '2507140814.0'}), (1027, {u'total_supply': '99807496.0', u'quotes': {u'USD': {u'market_cap': '56961236045.0', u'percent_change_7d': '-2.88', u'price': '570.711', u'percent_change_1h': '-0.39', u'volume_24h': '1986760000.0', u'percent_change_24h': '-1.62'}}, u'max_supply': None, u'last_updated': 1527886459, u'name': u'Ethereum', u'website_slug': u'ethereum', u'symbol': u'ETH', u'id': 1027, u'rank': 2, u'circulating_supply': '99807496.0'}), (1, {u'total_supply': '17068825.0', u'quotes': {u'USD': {u'market_cap': '127372692798.0', u'percent_change_7d': '0.0', u'price': '7462.3', u'percent_change_1h': '0.03', u'volume_24h': '4962840000.0', u'percent_change_24h': '-1.29'}}, u'max_supply': '21000000.0', u'last_updated': 1527886475, u'name': u'Bitcoin', u'website_slug': u'bitcoin', u'symbol': u'BTC', u'id': 1, u'rank': 1, u'circulating_supply': '17068825.0'})])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't order a `dict`, but you can create a list of the `items` and have that sorted:

```
sorted(data.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1][u'rank'])
```